# What is interior point in openlayers3

Tags: openlayers-3

When I work with polygon, there is a function `geometry.getInteriorPoint()`. What does interior point mean. What point in polygon is this one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a point that falls within the polygon for sure and in most cases that point matches the centroid of the polygon. Generally, it is used for label placement

Answer (score 0):

My feature was a multypolygon so I had to do something like this in order to get the internal coordinates:

```
const multipolygon: MultiPolygon = this.selectedGeometry.getGeometry() as MultiPolygon
const polygon: Polygon = multipolygon.getPolygon(0)
const pos: Coordinate = initial(polygon.getInteriorPoint().getCoordinates())
```

The `initial()` is from loadash and it drops the last coordinate.